# Find the first value by category - dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to find out how to choose first and last date and quantity for each category, here ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO.

| ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO | WANTED_DATE_OLD | WANTED_DATE_NEW | BUY_QTY_DUE_OLD | BUY_QTY_DUE_NEW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 49562_1_9 |  | 27.01.2022 |  | 1 |
| 49562_1_9 | 27.01.2022 | 27.01.2022 | 1 | 2660 |
| 50081_1_1 |  | 31.01.2022 |  | 6 |
| 50081_1_1 | 31.01.2022 | 31.03.2022 | 6 | 6 |
| 50081_1_1 | 31.03.2022 | 31.03.2022 | 6 | 1210 |
| 50084_1_1 |  | 10.02.2022 |  | 1 |
| 50084_1_1 | 10.02.2022 | 10.03.2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 50084_1_1 | 10.03.2022 | 10.06.2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 50084_2_1 |  | 10.02.2022 |  | 60 |
| 50084_2_1 | 10.02.2022 | 08.04.2022 | 60 | 60 |
| 52370_1_1 |  | 13.05.2022 |  | 3000 |
| 52370_1_1 | 13.05.2022 | 13.05.2022 | 3000 | 2000 |

In this original table I have the same ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO in more rows and I would like to "summarize" it like in the second table here:

| ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO | FIRST_DATE | LAST_DATE | ORIGINAL_QTY | LAST_WANTED_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 49562_1_9 | 27.01.2022 | 27.01.2022 | 1 | 2660 |
| 50081_1_1 | 31.01.2022 | 31.03.2022 | 6 | 1210 |
| 50084_1_1 | 10.02.2022 | 10.06.2022 | 1 | 1 |
| 50084_2_1 | 10.02.2022 | 08.04.2022 | 60 | 60 |
| 52370_1_1 | 13.05.2022 | 13.05.2022 | 3000 | 2000 |

So basically in the column FIRST_DATE we have the first value from column WANTED_DATE_NEW (for each category), in LAST_DATE the last value from WANTED_DATE_NEW, in ORIGINAL_QTY is the first value from BUY_QTY_DUE_NEW and in LAST_WANTED_QTY we have the last value from BUY_QTY_DUE_NEW.

I tried to use FIRSTNONBLANK and LASTNONBLANK functions, but they only work fot dates, not for all quantity - for example for 52370_1_1 quantity.
My code in creating new table from another in powerBI was:

```
PURCH_ORD_LINE_UNIQUE =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    DISTINCT ( PURCH_ORD_LINE_ARCH[ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO] ),
    "FIRST_DATE",
        CALCULATE (
            FIRSTNONBLANK (
                PURCH_ORD_LINE_ARCH[WANTED_DATE_NEW],
                PURCH_ORD_LINE_ARCH[WANTED_DATE_NEW]
            ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( PURCH_ORD_LINE_ARCH, PURCH_ORD_LINE_ARCH[ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO] )
        ),
    "LAST_DATE",
        CALCULATE (
            LASTNONBLANK (
                PURCH_ORD_LINE_ARCH[WANTED_DATE_NEW],
                PURCH_ORD_LINE_ARCH[WANTED_DATE_NEW]
            ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( PURCH_ORD_LINE_ARCH, PURCH_ORD_LINE_ARCH[ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO] )
        ),
    "ORIGINAL_QTY",
        CALCULATE (
            FIRSTNONBLANK (
                PURCH_ORD_LINE_ARCH[BUY_QTY_DUE_NEW],
                PURCH_ORD_LINE_ARCH[BUY_QTY_DUE_NEW]
            )
        ),
    "LAST_WANTED_QTY",
        CALCULATE (
            LASTNONBLANK (
                PURCH_ORD_LINE_ARCH[BUY_QTY_DUE_NEW],
                PURCH_ORD_LINE_ARCH[BUY_QTY_DUE_NEW]
            )
        )
)
```

Sorry if my question is too stupid, I'm quite new to DAX and PowerBI.
Thanks for any answer.
Tomas

Comment: Please provide the sample data as a copyable
[markdown table](https://tableconvert.com/markdown-generator)

Comment: @Peter - Is it ok now?

Comment: @TomasHalmazna for the sample 50081_1_1, you have two same latest dates with different BUY_QTY_DUE_NEW, in this case, which should you prefer , the maximum one ?

Comment: @UmutK the last one. I was thinkink about using LASTNONBLANK() function, but it doesn't work as I would like to.

Comment: @TomasHalmazna you should also add the codes you've tried so far to your question...

Comment: @UmutK - edited. It might be a bit confusing, so hopefully you can get it

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution : (i will share the sample file at the end, so you can easily understand my approach)

First we will add an index column to the table :

```
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type)
```

then, we will add grouped index number column :

```
Group Ranking =
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        EARLIER ( 'Table'[ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO ] ) = 'Table'[ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO ]
    ),
    'Table'[Index],
    ,
    ASC,
    DENSE
)
```

finally, we create our table :

Modelling --> New Table

```
Result Table = 
ADDCOLUMNS (
    SUMMARIZE ( 'Table', 'Table'[ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO ] ),
    "FIRST_DATE", CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Table'[WANTED_DATE_OLD ] ) ),
    "LAST_DATE", CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[WANTED_DATE_new ] ) ),
    "ORIGINAL_QTY",
        VAR _max =
            CALCULATE (
                MIN ( 'Table'[Group Ranking] ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO ] ),
                NOT ( ISBLANK ( 'Table'[BUY_QTY_DUE_OLD ] ) )
            )
        RETURN
            CALCULATE (
                FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'Table'[BUY_QTY_DUE_OLD ], 1 ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO ] ),
                'Table'[Group Ranking] = _max
            ),
    "LAST_WANTED_QTY",
        VAR _max =
            CALCULATE (
                MAX ( 'Table'[Group Ranking] ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO ] )
            )
        RETURN
            CALCULATE (
                SUM ( 'Table'[BUY_QTY_DUE_NEW] ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[ORDER_LINE_RELEASE_NO ] ),
                'Table'[Group Ranking] = _max
            )
)
```

[image: result]

---

[Here is the sample PBix File for you...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fmggDdpa4oJOxykJg1zJi3J4rtNvBMIS/view?usp=sharing)

---